# Python Sorting directories based on number of files, Stanford Dogs Dataset Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, directory-structure

I need to sort directories based on the contents they have in descending order. I have tried multiple approaches like renaming them based on the contents they have but in search of a reliable solution.
Actually, I need to create an unbalanced dataset of Stanford Dog Breeds and for that purpose, I need to remove 2 images from every class (i.e there is a maximum of 252 images in the top class, then 250, 248, 246 and so on) and need to arrange them in decreasing order. Currently, I am saving the directory path and number of contents in a dictionary and sorting it in reverse order but don't know how to feed the dictionary of each class directory to PyTorch ImageFolder. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the relevant code and directory structure? If you have the paths saved in a *dict*, then the easiest option would be to construct a custom dataset to fetch them.

Comment: Hi @Ivan, can you please provide me with any example for constructing custom dataset from dictionary of paths

Comment: First please provide the relevant code and directory and dictionary structures.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.